# Using Python and BeautifulSoup, select only text nodes that are NOT wrapped in <a>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some text sot hat I can urlize (wrap with  tags) links that are not formatted.  Here's some example text:

```
text = '<p>This is a <a href="https://google.com">link</a>, this is also a link where the text is the same as the link: <a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>, and this is a link too but not formatted: https://google.com</p>'
```

Here's what I have so far from [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/):

```
from django.utils.html import urlize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

def urlize_html(text):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    textNodes = soup.findAll(text=True)
    for textNode in textNodes:
        urlizedText = urlize(textNode)
        textNode.replaceWith(urlizedText)

    return = str(soup)
```

But this will also catch the middle link in the example causing it to be doubly wrapped in `<a>` tags.  The result are something like this:

```
<p>This is a <a href="https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/" target="_blank">link</a>, this is also a link where the test is the same as the link: <a href="https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/" target="_blank">&lt;a href="https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/"&gt;https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/&lt;/a&gt;</a>, and this is a link too but not formatted: &lt;a href="https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/"&gt;https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/&lt;/a&gt;</p>
```

What can I do to `textNodes = soup.findAll(text=True)` so that it only contains text nodes that are not already wrapped in `<a>` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Textnodes retain their `parent` reference, so you could just test for `a` tags:

```
for textNode in textNodes:
    if textNode.parent and getattr(textNode.parent, 'name') == 'a':
        continue  # skip links
    urlizedText = urlize(textNode)
    textNode.replaceWith(urlizedText)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup is beautiful!